# Create Ad-hoc wifi on Android (Samsung galaxy note 3)

Tags: networking, samsung-galaxy-note-3, ad-hoc-networks

I am creating a website using flask (python) to hold pre-downloaded episodes of anime and cartoons to take into school and host between me and my cartoon club. I want to run it on my Samsung galaxy note 3. Python is not a problem but I need to create a private, ad-hoc (I don't want all my data used up) network to run the site on and let my friends connect (also android phones, mostly). My phone is rooted, but theirs aren't. I can run a private hotspot but I don't need the whole internet, (nor the exorbitant costs). Any ways to do this?

Comment: Cut off the internet connection (i.e. disable mobile data)? Not sure if the hotspot will still open then (not tried).

Comment: Shame, this could have been perfect but it just says 'turn on mobile data'.

Comment: I was afraid of that. There might be a (root-based) work-around for that; I vaguely remember having read something like that in the past but cannot remember any details.

Comment: Ah! I knew it was somewhere around. Please check: [Can my phone act as a WiFi access point without mobile data?](/q/51751/16575) // [Can my phone act as WiFi Access Point while Disabling Celluar Radio?](/q/98468/16575)